# How to hide the pagination of boot strap table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, pagination

Can any one help me on toggle pagination for a bootstrap table.
the below is the code i have tried to hide pagination.

```
$table.bootstrapTable('togglePagination');
```

The above code causes server call every time. Is there any other way to hide pagination with out server call.

Comment: Increase the height of table and increase number of rows to be displayed at a time might work.

Answer (score 0):

Look "[Client Side Pagination](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/client-side-pagination.html)' and "[Table Options](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/)". You should set the `pagination` option to `false`. For example, by the `data-pagination` attribute.

```
<table id="table" data-pagination="false">
```

Comment: Hi Gleb, thanks for your update. but what i need is i have a buttons when i click on that need to hide the pagination for bootstrap table can you please let me know how can i set the above property.

Comment: @rap Please show me a working example of what you have already done. So it would be easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `data-show-pagination-switch="true"` and triggering it doesn't cause a server call as of today.